# Problems installing Laravel 4 on Windows 7 using XAMP

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

After installing Composer, I then went to `c:\xampp\htdocs` and executed the following command:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel khandakhulu --prefer-dist
```

I then get the following error:

```
[Composer\Repository\RepositorySecurityException] The contents of http://packagist.org/p/laravel/laravel$a996426ffd2d6fcd0d9a 2dfdd97171b28b3d196d34061f15d79ce67004b9c19d.json do not match its signatur e. This should indicate a man-in-the-middle attack. Try running composer ag ain and report this if you think it is a mistake.
```

Comment: Try running composer create-project laravel/khandakhulu --prefer-dist

Comment: If I do composer create-project lavarel/khandakhulu --prefer-dist I get [InvalidArgumentException]
Could not find package laravel/khandakhulu with stability stable

Comment: Try this: `composer create-project laravel/laravel khandakhulu --prefer-dist`. To be fair, @pleasedeleteme already suggested this - it didn't work because of a small mistake.

Comment: You may also try [Laravel installer](http://laravel.com/docs/installation#install-laravel), it's faster than composer installation.

Comment: I did use the --prefer-dist flag but forgot to include it in my original question. I am thus still stuck with the problem.

Comment: I have also downloaded  the latest version of the Laravel framework namely, laravel-master.zip file and copied it into c:\xampp\htdocs. I then unzipped it and executed composer install within the directory that contains the composer.json file. I still get the same error unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Basically we need to force the composer use https repository at composer.json as we know from [Laravel.io Forum](http://laravel.io/forum/06-10-2014-problems-installing-laravel-4-on-windows-7)

But we don't have any skeleton of laravel project. So, use [Laravel Installer](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#install-laravel) instead. This global installation generate composer.json at `~/.composer/composer.json` and modify to this

```
{
    "require": {
        "laravel/installer": "~1.1"
    },
    "repositories": {
        "packagist": { "url": "https://packagist.org", "type": "composer" }
    }
}
```

First time installation of Laravel Installer maybe will get same error, after you force the respository URL. Finally, create your new Laravel application.

```
~/.composer/vendor/bin/laravel -v new justapp
```